# In spring batch, How can pass parameter from ItemWriter to SkipListener?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

In my spring batch job, if while itemWriter is writing an error occurred, it is skipped. And ItemSkipListener received it and log item to file.

My item has one list data and i want know what element in list make error occurred.

But in ItemSkipListener, i can only know item and throwable. (cannot know what element in list)

So i think itemWriter pass list index to ItemSkipListener.
How can i do that?
thanks.

Comment: i found the solution, when exception occurred in writer, catch the exception and make new exception with index of element and etc. and throw it.
then in skipListener receive the throwable and can get the data.

Comment: Promote your comment to accepted answer for other users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution my self.
When exception occurred in writer, catch the exception and make new exception with index of element and etc. and throw it. then in skipListener receive the throwable and can get the data.